# Running a zabbix LLD pythonscript on a pfSense zabbix-proxy

Tags: python-2.7, zabbix

I have a pfSense router running a zabbix proxy. 
I created a python script to discover connected devices on the network. I want zabbix to monitor the devices. When i run the script (as user zabbix on the shell) i have valid output. When i have the zabbix proxy run it i get a error (with another script the error module was six):

```
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
ImportError: No module named site
```

I tried setting the $PYTHONHOME in a wrapper script like

```
export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib
export PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/root/bin
/scripts/MDU-dhcp-scrape.py $1
```

I can't get it to work anyone has a clue what i am doing wrong?

Comment: note that you have set PYTHONPATH, not PYTHONHOME

Comment: Thx, missed that. But still i get the error 
ImportError: No module named site
The error about the variable not set is gone

Answer (score 0):

I could not figure out the root cause of this. (i would still like to know it). But a workaround is to use cx_freeze or pyinstaller to create a standalone python script. This will do the trick. Downside is u need a FreeBSD box to freeze the script.